# iOS: How-to create a video chat one to one or one to many

Tags: ios, videochat

I have to create an app where users should be able to start a video chat with one contact (one to one) or more (one to many).
I spent almost all the entire day searching on google but I found nothing useful.
I have only found the [TokBox](http://www.tokbox.com/opentok/ios/docs/index.html) API.

I remember an app called cam (or something similar) done my Apple and I was thinking if here is any public API can be used for this.

Any help is really appreciated.

Tnx

Comment: +1. Have you found what you were looking for? I am also wondering if there is a decent opentok implementation out there, so far none.